# Whats with the fake crime?

Tags: simcity-2013

So, I,ve got a police station,right? Yes, and still, the people living *Closest* to the police station are worried about crime and moving out. The weirdest thing is, I'm constantly checking my charts, but still there is no crime...

Idk what this is about, does anyone know?

Comment: I saw this issue, seems the resident was occupied before the police station was built but after the station built it is not refreshing, delete the resident and new one will come won't complain